# Deneb Charts not showing on TV

Tags: vega-lite, deneb

We are trying to display dashboards with Power BI Deneb custom visuals using Vega-lite but all other charts except Deneb are showing up. We have tried with Yodeck (Rasberry PI) and Appspace.
It is strange only the deneb charts won't appear on the TV. They work fine in the browser.

Has anyone encountered something similar?

Comment: How are you showing them on the TV? Are you using the SVG or Canvas renderer?

Comment: I have tried both. All other charts show up but no vega lite / deneb. Very strange.
Even when I show an iframe vega lite page it gets blocked. I will keep you updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to get all Deneb charts appearing with a tool called Vue pilot. We installed the app on a Google Android TV and the apps can be managed through a cloud dashboard. Not a free solution but quite affordable. It costs approx $8 USD per screen/month. I have no affiliation with this company or product.

Here is Power BI Guy’s PL Dashboard:

[image]